# Evaluate XPATH 2.0 expression with SAXON

Tags: saxon, xpath-2.0

I struggeled to find a working SAXON example to perform a simple task like evaluating the following XPATH 2.0 expression:

```
abs(-a)
```

Evaluating an expression like

```
3 + 4
```

works quite fine, but I didn't manage to provide SAXON a value for the variable *a*.

I tried stuff like:

```
    final Processor proc = new Processor(false);
    final XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
    QName a = new QName("a");
    xpath.declareVariable(a);

    System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("abs(-a)", null));
```

But obviously this doesn't work since I didn't provide a value for *a*.

How can I declare a value for *a*?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit: This doesn't work either:

```
final Processor proc = new Processor(false);
final XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();

XPathSelector exp = xpath.compile("abs(-$a)").load();

exp.setVariable(new QName("a"), new XdmAtomicValue(17));
XdmItem result = exp.evaluateSingle();
```

This throws an exception:

> net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Undeclared variable in XPath expression: $a
>       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XPathCompiler.internalCompile(XPathCompiler.java:500)
>       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XPathCompiler.compile(XPathCompiler.java:472)
>       at xpathtest.SaxonTest.test(SaxonTest.java:26)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Undeclared variable in XPath expression: $a
>       at net.sf.saxon.sxpath.IndependentContext.bindVariable(IndependentContext.java:458)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseVariableReference(XPathParser.java:1905)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(XPathParser.java:1703)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:1638)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath(XPathParser.java:1564)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression(XPathParser.java:1529)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression(XPathParser.java:1541)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1419)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1390)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle(XPathParser.java:511)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionArgument(XPathParser.java:2629)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionCall(XPathParser.java:2371)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(XPathParser.java:1723)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:1638)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath(XPathParser.java:1564)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression(XPathParser.java:1529)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression(XPathParser.java:1541)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1419)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle(XPathParser.java:511)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExpression(XPathParser.java:450)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:386)
>       at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionTool.make(ExpressionTool.java:102)
>       at net.sf.saxon.sxpath.XPathEvaluator.createExpression(XPathEvaluator.java:153)
>       at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XPathCompiler.internalCompile(XPathCompiler.java:497)
>       ... 25 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it should be `abs(-$a)`. Note the `$`.

To provide parameters you can't use the "short-cut" method `XPathCompiler.evaluate()`. You have to do it the long way:

```
XPathSelector exp = xpath.compile("abs(-$a)").load();
exp.setVariable(new QName("a"), new XdmAtomicValue(17));
XdmItem result = exp.evaluateSingle();
```

Comment: I am still getting the *undeclared variable* exception. I've added your proposition and the stacktrace to the starting post.

Comment: You left out the `xpath.declareVariable()` before the `xpath.compile()`, which you got right in your original version.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old but I ran into this problem recently, and spent almost 2 hours searching for answers. Finally, I got this working with Saxon-HE 9.4. I kept getting an error from compile, in spite of declaring the external variable until I also called:

```
    xpath.setAllowUndeclaredVariables(true);
```